# AutoQuery / Ormlite-servicestack: Can I filter out soft deletes on a QueryDb class?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery, autoquery-servicestack

We have a few services built up with Ormlite/Servicestack and we are mostly pulling out database objects and POCOs using `QueryData` with custom logic.

However, we have one table that really doesn't need to be logically expanded on and works just fine querying the DB directly from the front end using AutoQuery and URL params. However, this table contains an `isDeleted` column to track soft deletes. The front end should not have any soft-deleted items, and we believe the front end shouldn't be able to get these records (i.e. shouldn't be responsible for querying the API with a `?&isDeleted=false`).

So, given our current setup:

```
[Route("/query/thing/stuff", HttpMethods.Get)]
public class secret_table: QueryDb<secret_table>
{
}
```

...would it be possible to implement a filter for the `QueryDb<>` to automatically exclude records where `isDeleted=true`? And would this be able to be applied only to this table/class?

I'm setting milk and cookies out in hopes that [mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) drops by and leaves a present...but any help is appreciated, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using one of the different [extensibility options](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#extensibility-with-queryfilters)?

You should also be able to use [OrmLite's Select Filter to enable Soft Deletes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#soft-deletes), e.g:

```
SqlExpression<secret_table>.SelectFilter = q => q.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true);
```

Note your AutoQuery DTO shouldn't reuse the name of the Table as the name of the DTO, use a different name like:

```
[Route("/query/thing/stuff", HttpMethods.Get)]
public class QuerySecretTable: QueryDb<secret_table> {}
```

Comment: mythz to the rescue again. Thanks for all you do for the community.
Side note: I think I accidentally downvoted you in my pocket yesterday and now my vote is locked in :( I'll ask some colleagues to help undo that mistake